# How do I see edits to my create-react-app after using npm run build?

Tags: reactjs, edit, npm-start, npm-run, surge.sh

I'm pretty new to React. I was following a course on Codecademy and working on a project called Jamming. Every time I'd start for the day, I'd used `npm start`. Then at the end, they had me deploy to surge.sh and use `npm run build`. After I finished the main project, they suggest ways to add on to get more practice. I was about to do that and started with my normal `npm start`, but it's not showing any edits. What am I missing? TIA

Comment: Are you checking the build version at surge.sh or the local version on your computer?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. They had me change the redirect URIs URL variable in the app and on Spotify to the deployed URL. I changed those back to the local and now it works.

Comment: Happy code @Trish